# I forgot my wireless router password. What do I do?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, password-recovery

I have a Linksys wireless router but I can't figure out what the password is.  I just got a new laptop and I can't connect via wireless. 
My old laptop seems to have the password set in the security settings but it doesn't show me the characters (just show dots) any help?

Comment: are we talking about the actual password for your 192.168... interface, or wep key ?

Comment: Also, what OS are you running?

Comment: plenty guesswork going on here, you should really provide more information! router model, operating system (of the old laptop), which password actually, admin or encryption key?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you referring to the router's web management password? If so, you'll probably have to reset the router to the factory default settings and then log in using the default password to reconfigure things.

Comment: Here's the reset button on a Linksys WRT54G: http://www.cguy.net/wireless_networking_guide/images/Linksys%20WRT54G%20back.jpg

Answer (score 5):

*i have a linksys wireless router but i can't figure out what the password is. i just got a new laptop and i can't connect via wireless. my old laptop seems to have the pwd set in the security settings but it doesn't show me the characters (just show dots) any help?*

It is a little vague from here told, is it truly a matter of a forgotten password (like the one you need to access your 192.168.1.1 router interface) or a matter of a wep key.

If it's the other, you might try these [tools from Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/password_recovery_tools.html). They truly have a tool for every occasion.

[image]

I'd (like someone already in here) recommend router reset, but with a warning: do it only as a last resort. Router reset will reset it to factory settings. Which is not always what you have it on now (as some ISP's modify the firmware to suit their own needs ... like mine for example, adding annex2 which makes it differ from the original version).

Comment: +1 Since he "can't connect via wireless", I think he's trying to recover his WEP/WPA key: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html

Comment: agreed; this seems supported by the OP's details.

Answer (score 3):

if you haven't reset the router yet, and you still have the password saved in firefox try this:

http://www.downloadsquad.com/2007/11/28/how-to-reveal-hidden-passwords-in-firefox/

if you use another browser, google for that browsers equivalent

Answer (score 2):

- Connect a CAT5 from your computer to your router
- Go to http://192.168.1.1
- Browse to `Wireless -> Wirless Security`, http://ui.linksys.com/files/WRT54GS/v5-v6/1.50.7/WSecurity.htm
- Write down password

Comment: what do you mean CAT5?

Comment: @Pacerier, I should have said "ethernet patch cable"; CAT-5 is a common type.